# How to manually check the parameters of mysql_connect() function via cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I'm often stuck when i need to specify the correct parameter values for the `mysql_connect()` method. That is, the right values of **IP** (server IP or `localhost`), username and password.
Is there any way to test the parameter values directly in cPanel ?

Comment: Please see [4.2.2. Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting.html). Also what do you mean by *"directly in cPanel"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly find the IP, database name and username from cpanel's MySQL Database section. However, it won't show you the password. However, you can manage db, user, permissions etc.

In most cases, your Database server will be in same server. So IP should be same or localhost. If it has database server in another IP, the provider will surely inform you earlier.

Comment: Understood the IP thing, as you said.
But confusion is also about username and password.
i have done a php code where the database username and password was use in mysql_connect(), while in other case, it was the username and password of the FTP which was used. Strange for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have your MySQL in a different machine/server, the host would be `localhost`. In rare cases you may need to write it as `127.0.0.1`.

The username should be listed in the "Users" part of the cPanels' databases page.

If you don't know the password, you can only change it.